# How to create an array of colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, color, arrays

I am trying to pass an array of colors (of any length) into a macro command to then be used when filling the background of tikz shapes. I've been successful, however, I ran into an issue with the `none` "color" (or lack thereof). In order to handle the string-to-color conversion with this special edge case, I have created the following working example using an if-condition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgf}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\newcommand{\Test}[2]
{%
    \readlist\mylist{#1}
    \readlist\colors{#2}
    
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}

    \foreach \Next [count=\i] in {#1}
    {%
        % Conditionally create the color variable with the correct color information.
        % Latex compiler will complain if you just try and use `fill=\colors[\i]` straight up.
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\colors[\i]}{none}}
        {%
            If \colors[\i] == none => TRUE!
            \def\mycol{none}
        }
        {%
            If \colors[\i] == none => FALSE!
            \def\mycol{\colors[\i]!100}
        }
    
        % Print the array elements to the document output.
        \i. \mylist[\i], \colors[\i]\\
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \filldraw  [fill=\mycol,
                        draw=orange] (0.1in,0.1in) rectangle ++(0.5in,0.5in);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\Test{hello, world, township}{none, green, blue}
%\Test{hello, world, township}{green, none, blue}

\end{document}
```

(This was compiled on [Overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com) using the XeLaTeX compiler.)

This produces the correct output:
[image]

But, if I try and use `none` in any other spot other than the first spot in the color input array, it stops working and the compiler freaks out at me. For example, if you uncomment the line `\Test{hello, world, township}{green, none, blue}`, the following happens:
[image]

Compiler error:
[image]

As shown in the output, the if-else statement stops working and produces incorrect results now. Even though I am comparing the strings `none` and `none`, it equates them as `false` when looking at array position 2+.

**Does anyone know why my array of color logic is not working in this case?**
**Why does the if-condition stop working as expected?**

Comment: Remove the space

Comment: :( well I feel dumb. That fixed it. Is there a way to santize the spaces away (i.e. trim the before and after spaces)?

Comment: yes, will figure out later. If you want to learn expl3 there's  \tl_trim_space etc.s, and if you want to learn Lua the solution is obvious.

Comment: @Code use the star version of `readlist*{}` can ignore the space.

Comment: @Tom Hello again! haha That star fixed the space issue I was observing. If you post a solution to this question, I'd be happy to accept and give you the reputation points. Or else, I will post an answer to my question after some time! :)

Comment: It was a good question, but questions that can be answered by a comment pointing to a typographical mistake normally get closed here.

Comment: @Davislor Ah yeah, that's fair

Comment: @Code That's fine. I am going to say that as well. Maybe close this.

Comment: @Code There is one thing I wanna mention. I notice you use `\gdef` for the `\mycol`. Are you mean to use `\mycol` outside the tikz environment? But this won't work because the `\i` was defined inside the tikz environment. To make `\mycol` work outside, you need '\global\edef'. This will turn `\i` to a real number when you use `\mycol` outside.

Comment: @Tom I was trying a bunch of stuff and it was not my intention to make this definition global. It's hard to know from my end what the Tex compiler is doing. The color is just supposed to be used within the loop, so just using `\def` would b enough. However, I still appreciate you pointing this out, because you're right about `\i` not existing outside the loop. The change you mentioned for `\global\edef` is something that will come in handy later!

Comment: @Tom I just revised my above code solution to replaced `\gdef` for `\def` (despite this question just about to be closed).

Comment: @Tom please note that `\global\edef` is `\xdef` (should be preferred).

Comment: @Skillmon Nice to know, thank you!

Comment: @CodeDoggo since you're looping over `#1` using `\foreach` you can drop the `\readlist\mylist{#1}` and use `\Next` instead of `\mylist[\i]`.

Comment: Also, I'd advice to remove the blank lines from your code, and the stray spaces (put a `%` after the closing and opening braces). If you need a paragraph use an explicit `\par`.